# What is the most frequently used name for hook-and-loop fastener in daily life?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook-and-loop_fastener
It has many names.
Hook-and-loop fasteners,
hook-and-pile fasteners,
touch fasteners, and
velcro.

My question is simple. Which is the most frequently used name in our daily live? I ask because the name Hook-and-loop fasteners is too long. I doubt people use it in daily life. Usually names that long have alternative short names. so I would like to confirm if it is velcro. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In speech velcro is probably the most common. It certainly is in my experience. However in writing the word may need to be avoided for legal reasons.

Comment: I'd say only avoid it if absolutely necessary. Velcro is the common name for this item; anything else would be extremely weird in most contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Probably depends on on the country, but velcro would be the most common.